# Visual Studio Tools for Cordova App Error On Application Loader

Tags: cordova, ios9

I have previous uploaded the ios build of a VS tools for cordova app on itunes connect for beta testing. Now uploading gives error code ITMS-90474 after the ios9 release.
Is this a known error as google is returning no results related to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

work **Requires full screen = YES;**

Comment: I did that and a different error appeared on publishing with beta tool. So I updated to release version and all is well. Thanks fam.

Comment: To be more precise, in plist add <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key><true/>

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a new requirement for app since iOS9 release. My app supported only landscape, got that error and rejected when uploading to App Store. I have solved that problem by selecting all four Device orientations (Targets -> General) and then added bellow code to ViewController:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
}
```